# What is the best way to evaporate toluene?

Tags: solvents, extraction

I decided to use toulene as my non-polar solvent because it's easy to get it. My question is, what is the best way to evaporate the toluene from the soaked organic material?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a bit more information. What are you really trying to do? Do you have some organic product (what, how much) that was synthesized/purified in toluene (how much)? A sponge? ;) You get the idea. Also, welcome to Chemistry.SE!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. Have a look at the [help] to learn how to post good questions, and hopefully get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well if your product were a volatile liquid, than toluene's $\pu{110 ^\circ{}C}$ boiling temperature (of the pure solvent at atmospheric pressure) may be dangerously high.

If you aim for a solid of low volatility, evaporate it under the reduced pressure of a membrane pump and gentle warming by a water bath.  If accessible, a rotary evaporator is a good thing for this: lower the pressure gradually to about $\pu{70 mbar}$, then increase the bath temperature to $\pu{60 ^\circ{}C}$.

Comment: If you have an acid or amine, you can attempt to extract into water, neutralize, and back extract into ether.